# Why is listings' frame width a little larger then \textwidth?

Tags: listings, framed, width

Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    frame=single, % adds a frame around the code
}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
abc

\begin{lstlisting}
abc
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And the screen shot of the result:

[image: screen shot of the code]

Even I set the `\fboxsep` to zero, I still get the same result. Are there any way to make it a little smaller?

Since I have many tables and lstlisting frames in my tex code, I want all their width to be the same. For tables, its width can be set corrctly by `tabularx` package, such as `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}...`. But I don't know an idea to correctly set the `lstlisting`'s frame width.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The frame is put outside of the listings. Therefore `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` can be used to leave room for the frame.
The default for `framesep` is 3pt and the default for `framerule` is 0.4pt.

Result:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    frame=single, % adds a frame around the code
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
abc

\begin{lstlisting}
abc
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]